# GIF functionality in Chatter

Tags: chatter, help

Is there a way to enable GIF files to display and run in the activity feed of Chatter?

Comment: The one place where animated gifs are allowed is in work.com Thanks feed items. The thanks badges can have animated gifs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible.There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kKaKAAU) posted in idea exchange.